# Why does "echo '2' . print(2) + 3" print 521?

Tags: php

Can anybody tell the internal procedure of the below expression?

```
<?php echo '2' . print(2) + 3; ?>
// outputs 521
```

Comment: What is with the downvotes? 4 of them and no reason provided so far.

Comment: Such code should never be written in any sane situation... :) This is Matrix spoon-bending code.

Comment: Changing your title from 'what' to 'why does ...' might reduce the downvotes. Your question is an interesting one.

Comment: It actually makes a very good interview question.

Comment: Wont produce that on my machine, as short tags are disabled LOL!

Comment: @SalmanA That would be a great interview question. It was presented here sans context, as unrealistic code riddle. Which is less so. Not to speak of the lack of research or original thought (implied for homework and interview questions alike).

Comment: Um, `<?pho`? **PHO**? Is @SalmanA programming in PHO?

Comment: @SalmanA and i would answer that question with: "i don't know" .. just before leaving the interview.

Comment: @tereško: I would add "but I want to know" and not leave :)

Comment: <?php echo '2' . print(2) + 3; ?>  print(2)+3  is equivalent to print 2+3 and the output is 5 then echo '2' . print 2+3'  is equivalent to echo '2'. print x ou x can be any string and print will return 1 in all casses so the ouput of echo is '2' . 1 =>21 we concatunate it with the first 5 we get 521.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Echo a concatenated string composed of:

The string '2'
The result of the function print('2'), which will return true, which gets stringified to 1
The string '3'

Now, the order of operations is really funny here, that can't end up with 521 at all! Let's try a variant to figure out what's going wrong.

echo '2'.print(2) + 3;
This yields 521

PHP is parsing that, then, as:

echo '2' . (print('2') + '3')) 
Bingo! The print on the left get evaluated first, printing '5', which leaves us

echo '1' . print('2')
Then the left print gets evaluated, so we've now printed '52', leaving us with

echo '1' . '1' ;
Success. 521.

I would highly suggest not echoing the result of a print, nor printing the results of an echo. Doing so is highly nonsensical to begin with.

Comment: This is a horrible answer.

Answer (score 17):

`print` is not a function, so the parentheses don't work as you think. It's taking the value of the expression `(2) + 3` (`5`) and outputs it. It returns `1` itself, which is concatenated to `'2'`, which is then `echo`ed.

Comment: It first evaluates all the expressions. `print` is an expression which outputs a value while it's being evaluated. So it outputs before `echo`.

Comment: Very interesting: if I make echo '2'.(print 2) + 3; it will return 224. Notice (print 2) instead print (2).

Answer (score 8):

`print(2) + 3` will result in 5 (it is the same as `print (2 + 3)` or `print 2+3`. Since print is not actually a function in this case, the parentheses are mostly meaningless. One last thing to note is that the `print` gets evaluated before the `echo`.

The output so far is: `5`

`echo '2' . print` will result in 21 because print always returns 1

The output now is: '521'

Comment: +1 for for your excellent explaination....

Answer (score 3):

First the addition of 2 and 3 is done which results in 5 and that is output.

Next print returns `1` always. That return value is concatenated with `2` to get `21` which is then echoed.