# Explanation for PHP print adding weirdness

Tags: php

This is related to:
[Why does "echo '2' . print(2) + 3" print 521?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176046/why-does-echo-2-print2-3-print-521)

I was wondering why

print(99) + print(99) + print(99) + print(99);

shows 99100100100....

I'd like to learn about the quirks of PHP.

Comment: The explanation is the same as with the duplicate.

Comment: Your linked question already contains some good explanations. What's unclear still?

Comment: I read the other thread but I still don't understand how the question I asked works (print(99) + print(99) + print(99)...)

Comment: BTW it said that print(2) + 3 = print (2+3).... but I don't know how print(99) is getting the 1's from. I thought the first one would be 100 but it is 99...

Comment: The "first one" is actually the last `print` call (as in right-most) in your statement. It gets executed (printed) first

Comment: You would see the ordering better if you used four *different* numbers.

Comment: Yeah... print(10) + print(20) + print(30) + print(40); results in 40312111

Comment: In the future, you can feed the code to [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) and see the parse tree it generates. In this case, the generated tree is basically the same as outlined in Juhana's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Print is not a function, so `print(99)` is the same as `print 99`. We can remove the parentheses for clarity.

```
print 99 + print 99 + print 99 + print 99;
```

The expression is evaluated from the right, so it becomes

```
print (99 + print (99 + print (99 + print 99)));
```

The rightmost `print` executes first, printing "99" and evaluating to 1.

Output:

```
99
```

Code left to be evaluated:

```
print (99 + print (99 + print (99 + 1)));
```

Again, the rightmost print is executed and it prints 99+1 ("100") and evaluates to 1.

Output:

```
99100
```

Code left to be evaluated:

```
print (99 + print (99 + 1));
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The `print` function produces output and then (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)) returns the value 1.  To further complicate things, the `print` function is a language construct (see the documentation) which does not require the parenthesis.

So, if you had the statement

```
print(99) + print(99);
```

What you are actually seeing is the printing of a 99, from the right-most `print`, followed by the result of `print(99) + 1;` which, due to the language construct, is the same as `print 99 + 1;` or `print (99 + 1);`.

Comment: +1 Better explained than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because, [from the docs](http://php.net/print),

`print` …

> Returns **1**, always

Answer (score 1):

Because `print()` **always returns 1**. Check the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)
This is unlike echo() which does not return the value.

Both `print()` and `echo()` are not actual functions but language constructs.

Comment: Actually, `print` is not a real function at all. It's a language construct just like `echo`. It even says so in the first sentence in the docs …

Comment: The manual says "*`print` is **not** actually a real function (it is a language construct)*".